# How do you read sound from the speakers using Rust on Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, rust

I want to read the sound that comes from YouTube or Winamp or any other player using Rust on Windows 10. I can't find an example how to read sound from the sound card.

I want to do something like [Creating Shazam in Java](http://royvanrijn.com/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/) but in Rust and that listens to the speakers and not to the microphone.

Comment: your soundcard needs a loopback channel for that (often called stereomix on windows). Your audio input should then behave like any other microphone.

Comment: Or you could go old-school and get a [male-to-male 3.5mm audio cable](http://www.lunashops.com/images/upload/Image/4-poles-3_5mm-cable-mm-1.jpg) and directly hook up the output to the input ^_^.